# Центрирование div внутри div

Tags: html, css

```
<div>
    <div></div>
</div>
```

Как сделать так, чтобы внутренний div оказался в центре родительского? Оба блока имеют фиксированные ширину и высоту. Возможно ли сделать эту конструкцию резиновой?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<style>
    #outer {
        width: 50%;
        background: yellow;
        position: relative;
        height: 200px;
    }
    #inner {
        width: 50%;
        background: blue;
        position: absolute;
        top: 25%;
        left: 25%;
        height: 100px;
    }
</style>
<div id="outer">
    <div id="inner"></div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9Sqb3/